# Performing operation on received TCP data(LwIP)

Tags: c, tcp, stm32, ethernet, lwip

So, I am receiving TCP data from client side, I want to gather the data in string format and perform certain operations based on the data and give back a message to the client.

Here is the code that I have written:-

```
err_t recv_callback(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *tpcb, struct pbuf *p, err_t err)
{

    if(p == NULL)
    {
        tcp_close(tpcb);
        return ERR_OK;
    }

    memcpy(data, p->payload, p->len);

    if(strcmp(data,"111") == 0)
        {
            tcp_recved(tpcb, p->len);
            sprintf(msg,"%s: Integer data was sent", p->payload);
            tcp_write(tpcb, msg, strlen(msg), 0x02);
            pbuf_free(p);

            err = ERR_OK;
            return err;
        }
    else if(strcmp(data,"hello world") == 0)
    {
        tcp_recved(tpcb, p->len);
        sprintf(msg,"%s: String data was sent", p->payload);
        tcp_write(tpcb, msg, strlen(msg), 0x02);

        pbuf_free(p);

        err = ERR_OK;
        return err;
    }

    else if(strcmp(data,"!!!") == 0)
    {
        tcp_recved(tpcb, p->len);
        sprintf(data,"%s: Special character data was sent", p->payload);
        tcp_write(tpcb, msg, strlen(msg), 0x02);

        pbuf_free(p);

        err = ERR_OK;
        return err;
    }

    else
    {
        tcp_recved(tpcb, p->len);
        sprintf(msg,"%s: Data could not be interpreted.", p->payload);
        tcp_write(tpcb, msg, strlen(msg), 0x02);

        pbuf_free(p);

        err = ERR_OK;
        return err;
    }
}
```

The thing is, this code is behaving in this way, if I send "hello world" from the client side to the computer, it returns- 'hello world: string data was sent', and after that when I send "111" or "!!!", it returns "Data could not be interpreted".

I re build the program and flash it again. This time, I send "111" first and the servers send back-'111: Integer data was sent' and 'could not interpret for the remaining'.

And also, along with the message I am getting a lot of jargon, can someone explain the reson behind the jargon data?

Like this is the data that I am getting

```
hello world
hello worldJwÚ: String data was sent
111
111UUU£å©2£å©2£å©2£å©2£å©2£å©2£å©2£å©2£å©2£å©2£å©2£å©2: Data could not be interpreted.
!!!
!!!UUU»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯»Ç¯!eÊdmu: Data could not be interpreted.
hello world
hello world"Æ©: String data was
```

```
111
111UUUórõNórõNórõNórõN®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv: Integer data was sent
!!!
111UUUórõNórõNórõNórõN®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv®½uv: Integer data was½ent
hello world
hello world›ã|ð: Data could not be interpreted.
```

Comment: What's `p`? What's `tcpwrite()`? Where and how was `msg` declared?

Comment: The buffer `data` seems to not have the string terminal (usually it is NULL character). Try to `data[p->len] = '\0'` after the `memcpy` line.

Comment: @Haris, `p` is the struct which holds data from the TCP packet. `tcp_write()` is the function to enqueue the data to be sent. `msg` was declared this way: `char msg[100]`

Comment: @PeterLee, Thank you, your idea seems to be effective. Also could you answer the jargon data part of my question? Thank you

Comment: @confusedfresher it is just random existing data from the specified memory. When you try to print a buffer as string, it would print out everything from the given memory until it finds the terminal character `\0`